# Including a PDF for dvi output

Tags: pdftex, tex-core, pdfpages

I want to include a multipage-pdf in latex and get `.dvi` output. I know `\include{pdfpages}`  only works with pdfLaTeX. I can't convert PDF to `.eps` since it is multi-page. I want to have `.dvi` output with a PDF included. Any way to do that?

Comment: Why do you need `.dvi` output? Why not split the PDF into separate pages and convert each to `.eps` format?

Comment: I have the same question. I want to embed a the PDF output of a Latex document into another one (with the ability to select the range of pages to be included). Using PDFLatex compiler, it is easy using the 'pdfpages' package. However, now I need to do it with Latex compiler for a document.

Answer (score 6):

You can convert the `PDF` file to `EPS` file*s*. Either you select page by page or depending on the converter this can be done in one conversion pass.

**`pdftops`** (from `xpdf`) knows the following options that are useful here:

- `-f <int>` specifies the first page
- `-l <int>` specifies the last page
- `-eps` converts to `EPS`

Command line for the second page of test.pdf written to `test02.eps`:

```
pdftops -eps -f 2 -l 2 test.pdf test02.eps
```

**`ghostscript`** can select pages and write to multiple output
files. Example from above:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=epswrite -sOutputFile=test%02d.eps
```

This writes files `test01.eps`, `test02.eps`, and `test03.eps`. `%02d` means,
the page number with at least two digits are written with a leading zero if necessary
(numbers < 10).

Also single pages can selected with ghostscript:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=epswrite -dFirstPage=2 -dLastPage=2 -sOutputFile=test02.eps test.pdf
```

Also `-sOutputFile=test%02d.eps` can be used here, `%02d` will be replaced by
the page number `02`.