# Emoji in DVI? (dvilualatex, dvisvgm and twemojis)

Tags: luatex, includegraphics, dvi, dvisvgm

### Motivation

I want to use emojis in [Manim](https://manim.community/), an animation software which uses LaTeX for rendering in the background. The pipeline is:

1. generate a TeX file
2. run `dvilualatex` on it to convert it to DVI
3. run `dvisvgm` to convert the DVI to SVG

I found out that the [twemojis](https://ctan.org/pkg/twemojis) package imports a PDF for each emoji. While [PDF cannot be imported directly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65852/51512), it is easy to batch-convert all the emojis to EPS, so this sounds like a reasonable approach. However, it is not as simple as it might seem – for some reason, the spacing around the **imported EPS files have really weird spacing** around them.

### Step-by-step reproduction

1. Download the twemojis package: https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/twemojis.zip
2. Unzip it, go to `./pdf-twemojis` and choose one emoji – for example `1f622.pdf`
3. Convert it to EPS using `pdftops -level3 -eps 1f622.pdf 1f622.eps`
4. Create a minimal `example.tex` file:

```latex
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvisvgm]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Hello \includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{./1f622.eps} world.
\end{document}
```

5. Convert it to DVI using `dvilualatex example.tex`
6. Convert it to SVG using `dvisvgm example.dvi`
7. The resulting file has a weird space:
   [image: SVG output]

.

This seems to be a problem with `dvilualatex`, not `dvisvgm`. Viewing the DVI file in Okular produces a similarly broken result:
[image: DVI in Okular]

The entire source folder of this example is available [here](https://gist.github.com/m93a/cf508bcba90d8d07a17339729281dff0#file-example-tex).

### Question

**What is causing this weird spacing and how do I get rid of it?** I could just place a large negative space after every emoji, but it feels very hacky and likely to break once I change the size of the font or the environment (eg. to `equation` or `align`).

Comment: Manim offers [three compiler options](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.utils.tex.TexTemplate.html#manim.utils.tex.TexTemplate.tex_compiler): _latex_, _pdflatex_ and _lualatex_. I don't know what exact commands are called for the other two, so I can't test it outside of Manim, but the result in Manim has the same weird spacing for each option. I would prefer to stick to the TeX → DVI → SVG pipeline, since if I wanted to use a different one, I'd have to fork Manim and reimplement a lot of stuff.

Comment: Removing `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` didn't change the output SVG, it just made the intermediate DVI unopenable in Okular.

Comment: I think the compiler options in Manim are just confusingly named – I'm pretty sure that each method compiles to DVI and then uses `dvisvgm` to convert to SVG. For example, choosing the _lualatex_ option compiles using the `dvilualatex` command.

Comment: if I remove the preview option your workflow works for me.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't quite follow the development, but imho dvisvgm can handle luatex + open type fonts since last year.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ohh I think I saw some discussion but hadn't seen that had rolled out, OK I'll delete most comments above

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm not sure, but Marcel will know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preview calculation appears off. If you surround it with `\fbox` to debug the size it works, even if you make the fbox rule invisibly thin:

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvisvgm]{graphicx}
\setlength\fboxrule{1sp}
\begin{document}
Hello \fbox{\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{1f622.eps}} world.
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, thank you! But do you have any idea why? O.o

Comment: @m93a no sorry I didn't trace, I added `\fbox` just to see whether the extra space came inside or outside the box, just to start debugging where it came from. But there was no space, so I set the rule width to 0 but the space came back, so set it to 1sp and gave up but posted the answer....